# How RuntimeTypeModel can be used to associate ProtoInclude with a type in protobuf-net?

Tags: .net, protobuf-net

As I understood, RuntimeTypeModel allows to associate ProtoInclude with a type, which is useful for cases when the type declaration cannot be changed. But I find it hard to understand how it is actually done.

Is there an example?

Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`AddSubType()` is used to specify derived types, along with their identifier; for example ([full code](http://protobuf-net.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/protobuf-net.unittest/Meta/Inheritance.cs)):

```
    static RuntimeTypeModel CreateModel() {
        var model = TypeModel.Create();
        model[typeof(NotInvolved)].Add(1, "D");
        model[typeof(SomeBase)]
            .Add(1, "A")
            .AddSubType(2, typeof(SomeDerived))
            .AddSubType(3, typeof(AnotherDerived));
        model[typeof(SomeDerived)].Add(1, "B");
        model[typeof(AnotherDerived)].Add(1, "C");
        model[typeof(AlsoNotInvolved)].Add(1, "E");
        return model;
    }
```

The above configures the entire type model at runtime, but you can also mix-and-match between automatic (via properties) and explicit (through code).

Comment: +1 @Marc Gravell: then we should use model.Serialize and model.Deserialize from there rather than ProtoBuf.Serializer.De/serialize<T>?  Also, does AnotherDerived derive from SomeBase in your example?

Comment: @sgtz definite yes, and yes from memory. In that order.