# Serialize and deserialize Object with non standard constructor - protobuf-net

Tags: c#, serialization, deserialization, protobuf-net

I have an object which

- does not have the Serializable attribute set
- Has properties, who's type, does not have the Serializable attribute set
- I do not have control over (meaning i cannot edit the class)

I tried reading [THIS](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/240621/How-to-serialize-data-effectively-Custom-serializa), it talks about substitution classes to fix this when using [Sharpserializer](http://www.sharpserializer.com/en/index.html) but frankly, I don't understand how to do this when I don't know the properties of my object.

are there some of serialization frameworks that can do this?

Edit: I'm looking into protobuf.net
I cannot figure out how to get it to work in my scenario though - Im hoping Marc will swing by to save the day? :) -
I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17563554/how-do-you-configure-protobuf-nets-runtimemodel-default-to-support-serializing#comment27254551_17563554) which is the exact same problem as mine, but I'm still getting
"Type is not expected and no contract can be inferred"
when using

```
private static byte[] ClienToBytes(IScsClient client)
{
    using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        RuntimeTypeModel.Default.Add(typeof(IScsClient), true).SetSurrogate(typeof(BinaryFormatterSurrogate<IScsClient>));

        Serializer.Serialize(memoryStream, client);
        return memoryStream.ToArray();
    }
}
```

am I using the RunTimeTypeModel wrong?

Comment: Is `IScsClient` an interface? or a class? Or better: do you have a *runnable example* (even if it doesn't actually work) of what you want to do?

Comment: Yay! - I think IScsClient is a class (bad naming maybe?) - I can create an object from it(can i do this with an interface?), that has properties like IscsWireProtocol WireProtocol - which is what i want to serialize and deserialize because it has some connection properties i need later on. I do have a runnable Test of what i want to do

Comment: and is the concrete implementation "obvious" (for some value of "obvious")? Or even better : can you share the declaration of `IScsClient` and any concrete implementation? (by email would help if you can't put it here for some reason)

Comment: IScsClient Client = ScsClientFactory.CreateClient(new ScsTcpEndPoint("160.209.1.100",10666)); this is about as concrete as it gets
Source for IscsClient is -> http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/155282/A-Complete-TCP-Server-Client-Communication-and-RMI

Comment: Well, sort of; I kinda need to know a: what the interesting properties of `IScsClient` are, and b: whether they are set via the instance (accessors) or via the `CreateClient` line.

Comment: the property types are non native (well there are some like datetime) but the rest is a part of the framework im using - and they are set via CreateClient and when i connect the using Client.Connect() it uses some internal logic to setup a socket which in turn gives me communicationState amongst other things

Comment: And is there enough information on an `IScsClient` to know how to create a new instance? i.e. if you had to clone one right now, and all you had was an `IScsClient` - could you do something like `var clone = ScsClientFactory.Create(source.Host, source.Port, source.Magic, source.Foo, source.Bar)` or something?

Comment: Basically - it is really hard to answer without the exact context; the answer could be "yes, like this", or "no, you need to rethink" - but I can't tell much without knowing the API involved

Comment: No, that is in fact my problem, else i would have create my own object to hold the values. I cannot recreate the object from the properties. I've listed the source in my third comment - btw. thank you so much for putting so much effort into this

Comment: Then: neither can protobuf-net (at least, not in any sane way); it isn't an internal state serializer. I would suggest thinking about what the **data is** that you need to configure the system; serialize just the data, and then *separately* map that to implementation. At the moment, my answer would be "no, this is not a good fit"

Comment: I should emphasise: between custom factory methods and type surrogates (both fully supported), many scenarios involving custom constructors are fine - just... Not really this one

Answer (score 0):

I would try protobuf-net. Take a look here:
http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/

Quote from Website:

> protocol buffers is the name of the binary serialization format used by Google for much of their data communications. It is designed to be:
>
> - small in size - efficient data storage (far smaller than xml)
> - cheap to process - both at the client and server
> - platform independent - portable between different programming architectures
> - extensible - to add new data to old messages

Comment: I've looked into this too, but doesn't seem be any easier to use non custom, non native classes

Comment: But you can Add Serializer for typoes you do not have the sourcecode in your hand, for example: `RuntimeTypeModel.Default.Add(typeof(Point), false).Add("X", "Y");`

Comment: but i cannot mark the type as a contract? - do i not need to do this?

Comment: You do not have to modify the classes. The class Point is from Namespace System.Drawing.Point and there is no serializer defined for that out of the box.

Comment: Do you have any examples of using the RuntimeTypeModel?

Comment: the above sample tells the serializer which properties should be serialized. For the struct Point i'm only interested in the Property X and Y and the rest i don't care, although there are others. More examples at: [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6088004/how-runtimetypemodel-can-be-used-to-associate-protoinclude-with-a-type-in-protob